# ¿Existe alguna función en C++ que ponga en mayusculas la primera letra de cada palabra dentro de string? (uppercase)

Tags: c++11

He estado buscando en la documentación pero no he encontrado una función en las librerias estandar de C++ que haga esto (tal vez no he sabido buscar bién).

Lo que quiero es esto:

Tengo un string así:

```
string = "palabra1 palabra2 palabra3";
```

y quiero que me la convierta en esto:

```
string ="Palabra1 Palabra2 Palabra3";
```

Solo quiero saber si existe una función estandar que lo haga. 
¿O tendré que implementarme una propia usando **toupper()**?

---

### -----------------------------ACTUALIZACIÓN-----------------------------------

Encontré una (No en las librerias estandar) pero si hechas con ellas. 
La Funte es esta.
http://vertstudios.com/blog/c-capitalize-word-proper-case/

Y el código este. Aquí lo dejo por si a alguien le es útil.

```
//Joseph McCullough
//Program: capEachWord.cpp
//Description: Takes a string and capitalizes each word of the string.
//Visit www.mcculloughdesigns.com/blog for more C++ Goods!

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void lowerCase(string&);
void capEachWord(string&);

const string SENTINEL = "0";//When entered as strToConvert,
              //terminates program.

int main()
{
  string strToConvert;  //The string that will be converted.

  cout << "***********************************" << "\n"
     << "CapEachWord.exe"                     << "\n"
     << "Capitalizes every word in a string." << "\n"
     << "Provided By McCullough Designs"      << "\n"
     << "***********************************";

  //Read in strToConvert
  cout << "\n\nEnter a String or enter 0 to exit: ";
  getline(cin, strToConvert);

  while (strToConvert != SENTINEL)
  {
    capEachWord(strToConvert);
    cout << "\nNew String: " << strToConvert;

    //Read in strToConvert
    cout << "\n\nEnter a String or enter 0 to exit: ";
    getline(cin, strToConvert);

  }
  return 0;
}


/****** function capEachWord *****
Description: converts the first letter of a word to a capital letter

PARAMETERS
  strToConvert: the string being manipulated

Precondition:
  strToConvert: undefined

  HEADERS
  #include <string>

Postcondition:
  Returns the string with the first letter of every word capitalized.  */

void capEachWord(string& strToConvert)
{
  //Identifies if the current word has been capitalized.
  //Set to false by default.
  bool thisWordCapped = false;
  //Turn all letters lowercase
  lowerCase(strToConvert);

  for (unsigned int i=0; i<strToConvert.length();i++)
  {
     //At a space or punctuation mark, the current word has ended.
     //We are now on a new word that has not yet been capitalized,
     //so thisWordCapped is set to false.
    if ((ispunct(strToConvert[i])) || (isspace(strToConvert[i])))
      thisWordCapped = false;

     //If current word has not been capitalized AND the current character
     //is a letter, uppercase the letter. The word is now capitalized, so
     //thisWordCapped is set to true, and will not be set to false until
     //a space or punctuation is found.
    if ((thisWordCapped==false) && (isalpha(strToConvert[i])))
    {
      strToConvert[i]=toupper(strToConvert[i]);
      thisWordCapped = true;
    }

  }

}
/****** function lowerCase *****
Description: makes all the characters of a string lowercase

PARAMETERS
  strToConvert: the string being manipulated

Precondition:
  strToConvert: undefined

  HEADERS
  #include <string>

Postcondition:
  Returns the string all lowercase */

void lowerCase(string& strToConvert)
{
   for(unsigned int i=0;i<strToConvert.length();i++)
   {
      strToConvert[i] = tolower(strToConvert[i]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No existe tal función, lo que podés hacer es implementar la tuya propia como dijiste:

```
string convertFirstToUpper(string s) {
    s[0] = toupper(s[0]);
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias por contestar!! Un Saludo!!

Comment: De nada! Espero que te sirva! Saludos! :D